# Do I always have to "wait" for page loads when using selenium on non-ajax pages?

Tags: asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bdd, specflow

I'm writing some BDD tests using Cucumber, Selenium and Xunit for a legacy ASP.Net application. The way the pages are designed, every "click" leads to a new page being fetched from the server. If I have to automate the tests for a particular page, should I have a line similar to the following after every "click"?

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
wait.Until(...); //Wait until something about the page is true
```

I'm not sure if Selenium would wait implicitly for page loads without my explicitly having to state this all the time. What is the recommended pattern to handle this scenario?

It's cumbersome to always have an idea of "some element" so that I can put it in the `Until` method and that leads to brittle tests. The ASP.Net pages are littered with lots of dynamic controls and a whole slew of page refreshes which makes the test code quite unreadable.

**My Proposed Solution:** Write an extension method that does the waiting implicitly and that takes a parameter of an element-id to wait on. But I'm just refactoring the above problem into a more manageable place. I still have a wait be explicitly performed. Is there no way to eliminate it? Does selenium have some obvious default that would handle this case without the need for such an extension method or is this really a natural way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your tests be reliable and wait only the exactly needed time interval - then yes, Explicit Waits with `WebDriverWait` is a perfect solution. And, it's actually a very *"natural"* solution - think about how you, as a user, define that the page loaded - it's usually when you see the desired content, correct? When you look at the loading page, you are constantly reevaluating the state of the page, checking whether the desired content appeared or not. Explicit Waits follow the same logic - by default, every 500 ms it checks if the expected condition is true or not, but no more than X seconds you've configured when instantiating the
`WebDriverWait`.

If you need to use `wait.until()` calls often and want to follow the DRY principle, think about applying the ["Extracting Method"](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) or other refactoring methods.

You can set the implicit wait which would be applied on every element search, or introduce hardcoded "artificial" delays, but that's not going to be reliable and would be time-wasteful - you'll end up waiting more than needed and having occasional test failures.

Comment: I see your point. What confuses me is the need for specifying the `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` when we already have a `wait.Until`. What's the former for? To timeout if the 'until' never happens?

Comment: @PhD yes, it's an upper bound, wait no more than X seconds and throw a timeout exception if the expected condition is not met.